# SQL Select with distinct last 10 characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Table phoneRecord has values:

```
14445556666
4445556666
7778889999
```

I want to select with distinct last 10 characters which will give me result:

```
14445556666
7778889999
```

Comment: typically you should post what you have tried as this is not a 'do it for me' site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this easily like this:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [value] VARCHAR(12)
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([value])
VALUES ('14445556666')
      ,('4445556666')
      ,('7778889999')
      ,('17778889992')
      ,('27778889992')
      ,('37778889992');

WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT [value]
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY RIGHT([value], 10) ORDER BY [value]) AS [rowID]
    FROM @DataSource
)
SELECT [value]
FROM DataSource
WHERE [rowID] = 1;
```

[image]

Note, that you must decided which of the `duplicates` records to leave, as they are not real duplicates. In my example, I am showing the smallest value using:

```
ORDER BY [value]
```

You can change this to something else.